# Unity A* Pathfinding Move backwards

Tags: unity, path-finding

I am using the A* Pathfinding project to move my character. More specifically i am using the `RichAI` component.

If you take a look at the below picture:

[image]

What you can see here is the NPC and a pivot point that shows that my character has to move to this location.

The way the character does so is by turning 180 degrees and then move towards the point.

However, this isn't really desirable for me as the NPC should be facing my player and then walk backward.

My question is how dI i tell A* not to turn around but instead walk backward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A* is an algorithm for finding a path.

The problem you pose does not appear to be about finding paths: it's about controlling the details about how an object traverses a path.

I do not know the libraries you're using, but I imagine you're looking in the wrong place for a solution; you want to look at whatever controls how objects actually travel along a chosen path.

Comment: after some digging i actually found that the RichAI component that follows with the A* pathfinding project is rotating the camera